# L.multiPolyline does not show anything on map (leaflet)

Tags: javascript, leaflet

This is my code to add a polyline to a map. The map works fine and I've used GeoJSON objects to display routes on the map.

```
var polyLine = L.multiPolyline(window.routeArray,{color: 'blue'});          
polyLine.addTo(map);
```

window.routeArray is an array of latLngs
This is the output if I do an `console.log(" " + window.array);`
(I'm using node.js with this.)

```
LatLng(49.24905, -123.11531),LatLng(49.24854, -123.07618),LatLng(49.24022, -123.07642),LatLng(49.24034, -123.09034),LatLng(49.23287, -123.09054),LatLng(49.23319, -123.10146),LatLng(49.24045, -123.10138)
```

The map doesn't show anything and I can't figure out why.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two suggestions, 1) what you've described is a polyline, not a multipolyline. 2) the points must be added as a javascript array as an array of arrays, for example

```
var line_points = [
    [38.893596444352134, -77.0381498336792],
    [38.89337933372204, -77.03792452812195],
    [38.89316222242831, -77.03761339187622],
    [38.89302861514842, -77.03731298446655],
    [38.892920059048464, -77.03691601753235]
];

var line = L.polyline(line_points).addTo(map);
```

[This example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/polyline/) may help

Comment: Does that draw a line through all the points specified? If yes, then what's the difference between that and a multipolyline?

Comment: mutlipolyline is for two or more unconnected lines, so another nested array, in the form `[line_points,  line_points2, ... ]`